# hyperlink in php html email not working

Tags: php, html-email

I am using below code to send email using php

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['emailbox'] ;
$message1 = nl2br($_REQUEST['output_textarea']);
$subject = 'script';
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor='Lavender' width='100%'>
<tr><td><font face=consolas>$message1</font></td></tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>

<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com">Hyperlink Code</a>

</body>
</html>
";
$headers  = "From: ase@abc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: anoop@abc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

But the hyper link mention in above code  `<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com">Hyperlink Code</a>` giving me below error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in eval()’d code on line 24
```

If I remove the the hyperlink line code from code, its working fine. how can I mention the hyperlink in email ?

Comment: what is code on line 24

Comment: `<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com">Hyperlink Code</a>`

Comment: double quote at `$message = "` conflicting with double quote at `<a href="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the syntax highlighting breaks in your code? Notice that it happens when you use double quotes?

The simple answer is the change out:

```
<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com">Hyperlink Code</a>
```

For:

```
<a href=\"http://www.hyperlinkcode.com\">Hyperlink Code</a>
```

But you can also do:

```
$message = <<<_E_
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor='Lavender' width='100%'>
<tr><td><font face=consolas>$message1</font></td></tr>
</table>

<br/><br/>

<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com">Hyperlink Code</a>

</body>
</html>
_E_;
```

It's called [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Hello sir, sorry to comment on such an old answer. I am running into a similar problem as this guy. I have escaped the double quotes using the forward slashes like you did and that works fine. My problem lies when I actually click the link in the email. All it does it just bring me to a silly blank page called "about:blank" in the address bar. Any idea how to fix this? @sammitch

Answer (score 0):

I think that the double quotes ("") are making some noise ¿?

Maybe you can try single quotes (''), like:

```
<a href='http://www.hyperlinkcode.com'>Hyperlink Code</a>
```

Sorry if i'm wrong..